# Visual Studio 2017 Randomly Breaks on Javascript without a breakpoint present

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

This is more of an annoyance than anything, but in Visual Studio 2017, often the jQuery javascript will hit an "invisible" break point and stop, on some arbitrary line of code. This only happens when my developer tools are not open in my browser. It's almost as if there's some metadata from old `debugger` statements or something like that. I ran into this issue occasionally in 2015 but it was exceedingly rare so I never worried about it. Has anyone else ran into this issue and have a solution?

Comment: No, but other issues were coming up for me and updating VS fixed them, just in case you're using an old build. It's updated quite regularly.

Comment: You've probably enabled "break on all exceptions" at some point and forgotten to turn it off. Normally, the IDE only breaks on an *unhandled* exception. But if you switch it to "break on all exceptions," it breaks when an exception occurs even if it's handled later. (jQuery does some things that involve it causing exceptions to be thrown but then handling them.) Turn the setting back off. (I don't have VS 2017 handy so can't quote the exact setting name...)

Comment: This is happening to me now. It's really annoying and I can't figure out why it is happening. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to press in Visual Studio Debug - Delete all breakpoints